# Drools - how to check input string is a number

Tags: java, jboss, drools

I want to check input string is a double in drools rule. Input is a string and I want to trigger the rule when the input string is a number(double). How can I write this condition in when sections of the rule?

```
rule "rule1"
when 
    (answer!=null && //mycode to check answer is double)
then
    //do something
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The very short answer is: you can't, and you shouldn't. To elaborate on this, Drools doesn't have an operator that can be applied to a String to produce a true or false. Java, however, provides a simple way: `java.lang.Double.valueOf( String s )`, but you can't use this in a constraint as it throws an exception whenever the String is not a valid number.

Thus, the short answer is: Write a function and call it:

```
function boolean isValid( String s ){
   try {
       Double.valueOf( s );
       return true;
   } catch( Exception e ){
       return false;
   }
}

rule "check"
when
    SomethingMissing( isValid( answer ) )
then ... end
```

You don't have to check for answer being null as the function handles this, too.

**But it so happens that this code triggers a bug in Drools, one in 5.4.0 and another one in 5.5.0. It works fine with 5.3.0.**

You may try another approach and use the pattern matching operator of Drools:

```
rule "check"
when
    SomethingMissing( answer != null and answer matches "???" )
then ... end
```

All you have to do is supply a regular expression for ??? representing everything you'd like to accept as a double. Since this isn't a Drools question, I'll leave it open.

Note, however, that a regular expression doesn't *really* tell you whether it is a valid double, since you can't check limits with a regular expression.

Comment: can you link to those bugs related to first approach you mention in your answer?

Comment: I've experimented with function isValid, and 5.4.0 and 5.5.0 crashed.

Comment: OK. I assumed you had a specific defect in mind and was looking for a JIRA ticket, just to document the case more clearly.

Comment: I used the pattern matching operator of drools. I supplied regular expression for ??? and it is successful. Thanks for your reply.It was very helpful.